# Python string to other classes

Tags: python, string, class, types

I have an 3rd party python method (ANSA) that returns strings based on user gui input with default values to start with.

The default values may look like this and are stored in a dictionary:

```
Label         Value
Userdata1     123
Userdata2     'abc'
Userdata3     123.456
...           ...
```

Now, these are all returned as a dictionary with string values by the 3rd party "back_box" function.

**Is it, based on the class of the default values, possible to change the new string class back to the default classes?**
Here is something that may make it a bit clearer:

```
data = {'Userdata1':123, 
       'Userdata2':'abc', 
       'Userdata3':123.456}

new_data = black_box(data) # Outputs dictionary with the values as strings

for i, var_name in enumerate(data):
        original_class = type(data[var_name])
        new_data[var_name] = new_data[var_name].StrToClass(original_class)
```

So what i am looking for is a method/function/magic trick called **strToClass** in the above example.

I know it may be a risky way to do it, but any ideas about pythonic ways to do it?

(python3 btw)

Comment: Changed the name of your `dict` to `data` since `def` cannot be set to a value in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the types of the original values of the dictionary in a separate new dictionary, then use that dictionary to transform them back --

```
>>> my_dict = {'Userdata1':123, 
               'Userdata2':'abc', 
               'Userdata3':123.456}
>>> type_dict = {k:type(v) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems()}
>>> type_dict
{'Userdata2': <type 'str'>, 'Userdata3': <type 'float'>, 'Userdata1': <type 'int'>}
>>> str_dict = {k:str(v) for k,v in my_dict.iteritems()}
>>> str_dict
{'Userdata2': 'abc', 'Userdata3': '123.456', 'Userdata1': '123'}
>>> new_dict = {k:type_dict[k](v) for k,v in str_dict.iteritems()}
>>> new_dict
{'Userdata2': 'abc', 'Userdata3': 123.456, 'Userdata1': 123}
```

Or, using your pseudocode

```
for i, var_name in enumerate(data):
    original_class = type(data[var_name])
    new_data[var_name] = original_class(new_data[var_name])
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! What i seem to have missed is the possibility to use class_type(variable) as you did in: 
    k:type_dict[k](v)

Comment: With python, if you think it would be pythonic to do, it probably is do-able :)

Comment: this fails with more complicated types say a set.
`set("set([1, 2, 3])")` -->>
`set([' ', 'e', '3', ')', '(', ',', '1', 's', '2', 't', '[', ']'])`

Comment: @Calpratt yes it could fail with many different types, was assuming more primitive types were passed and not data structures. If that is the case, the literal eval would be necessary (and as you've noted below even that can fail).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the magic function you're looking for is [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
for i, var_name in enumerate(data):
    new_data[var_name] = ast.literal_eval(new_data[var_name])
```

Answer (score 1):

**Never name a variable def**

For complicated classes you'll need more work, however this should do nicely for basic types, and types that have a representation identical to other basic types

```
d = {'Userdata1':123, 
       'Userdata2':'abc', 
       'Userdata3':123.456}
# create a list containing each type

var_type = [ type(d[key]) for key in sorted(d.keys())]

d = black_box(d)

import ast
for vt, key in zip(var_type, sorted(d.keys())):
    # if the variable was a string you're already done
    if not vt == str:
         # cast from string to generic type
         d[key] = ast.literal_eval(d[key])
         # cast from generic to original type
         try:
             d[key] = vt(d[key])
         except:
             print "Error converting dictionary value with key: " + key
             print "Unable to cast {} as {}".format(d[key], vt)
```